# Fecthing unit test cases in python automatically

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am using Python's unittest with simple code like so:

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(module1))
suite.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(module2))
```

I want my test suite to automatically parse all the modules and searches for all the unit test cases files that we have written?
for e.g.

there are 5 files,

1). f1.py

2). f2.py

3). f3.py

4). f4.py

5). f5.py

we dont know which of this file is the unit test case file. I want a way through which each file will be parsed and only the name of the module that has unit test cases should be returned

NOTE:- I am using python 2.6.6 so could not really make use of `unittest.TestLoaded.discover()`

Comment: I changed my unit-tests from unittest to py.test because of that reason.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tool, it completely changes your unit-testing life. You just run it in the source folder root like:

```
> nosetests
```

then it automatically finds all the test cases.

If you want also run all the doctests, use:

```
> nosetests --with-doctest
```

In case if you only want to find a list of modules programmatically, `nose` provides some API (unfortunately, not as convenient as `TestLoader.discover()`).

**UPDATE**: I've just discovered (pun intended) that there is a library called [`unittest2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) that backports all the later `unittest` features to the earlier versions of Python. I'll keep the code below for the archaeologists, but I think, `unittest2` is a better way to go.

```
import nose.loader
import nose.suite
import types

def _iter_modules(tests):
    '''
    Recursively find all the modules containing tests.
    (Some may repeat)
    '''
    for item in tests:
        if isinstance(item, nose.suite.ContextSuite):
            for t in _iter_modules(item):
                yield t
        elif isinstance(item.context, types.ModuleType):
            yield item.context.__name__
        else:
            yield item.context.__module__

def find_test_modules(basedir):
   '''
   Get a list of all the modules that contain tests.
   '''
   loader = nose.loader.TestLoader()
   tests = loader.loadTestsFromDir(basedir)
   modules = list(set(_iter_modules(tests)))  # remove duplicates
   return modules
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but do you any remedy for my problem. I will investigate nose for sure.

Comment: btw, just checked out nose is supported from python 3. I am using 2.6.6.

Comment: @BhupeshPant "supports python 3" means "*also* supports python 3 (some frameworks still don't)". I've been using it since 2.6.

Comment: oh then its cool... I will surely investigate more on this..but for now any solution for me?

Comment: @BhupeshPant see the update (especially what's written in bold).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) feature of the `unittest` library:

```sh
$ python -m unittest discover --start-directory my_project
```